# Chrome returns "Bad Request - Request Too Long" when navigating to local IIS Express

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, google-chrome, iis-express

I have a web application that runs perfectly fine when I use the Visual Studio 2010 development server (Cassini). However when I try to use IIS Express to host the site Chrome just displays a "Bad Request - Request Too Long" error.  The IIS Express site does display in other browsers (FireFox and IE9) so I'm kind of confused.  The error occurs in Chrome when I try request pages in my application or even basic resources like an image, so I don't think it is an issue with URL rewriting or routing.

Just to see if the problem was somehow a result of my site's code, I created a new MVC3 website and tried running that. This worked in the VS development server, but once again produced the "Bad Request" error when running under IIS Express.

I am about to start testing the site using some mobile devices so I need to get this running under IIS.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:
The root url of the site (http://localhost:50650/) is being requested using GET.  I am currently using Chrome v12.0.742.112.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

I get this all the time ONLY in Chrome and I have to clear browsing data to fix it.

Wrench > Tools > Clear Browsing Data

Check the following:

- Clear browsing history
- Clear download history
- Empty the cache
- Delete cookies and other site data

Then click "Clear Browsing Data" button and refresh your page.

**UPDATE:**
I figured out that it has to do with writing too many cookies to the browser and that if you just close all instances of Chrome, the error goes away for a while.  To prevent it, you'll need to clear out your cookies programmatically.

Comment: Thanks. This also resolves an issue with some danish authority sites, where we use a central login called nemid. Removed all cookies under the nemlog-in.dk. (including it here to be searchable :))

Comment: Or access the site in an incognito window.

Comment: This is an issue on ASP.net websites only. So clearing all the browsing data is not necessary.

Answer (score 52):

Instead of clearing all the cookies, just do the following:

- Right click the lock in the address bar area (see picture below)
- Under cookies there is a link saying how many cookies are used
- Click that link
- Remove all cookies in there (or just the troublesome if you can identify them)
- Problem gone

[image]

Answer (score 36):

This error is caused by a corrupt cookie for the website you are trying to view, so to clear it all you need to do is clear the bad cookie(s) for that website.

In Chrome, go to...

chrome://settings/cookies

(Or manually go to Settings->Advanced Settings->Privacy->Content->All Cookies and Site data)

From there, you can search for cookies that match the site you are having problems on. Finally, click "remove all" for the matching cookies.

Comment: This is significantly better than the accepted answer because it steers you towards being able to surgically fix the problem the OP had, this issue on localhost. The accepted answer works but it's like nuking something from orbit.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is usually that the site in question has accumulated too many cookies or created cookies which are too large, making the HTTP headers swell beyond the allowed maximum.

### One-time work-around

As has been mentioned, you can go to **Settings|Advanced|Content Settings|All Cookies and Site Data**, search for the site in question, and delete the cookies using the X button on the right.  This reduces the header size of the HTTP request when contacting the site.

### Long-term work-around

In addition to removing them one-time, however, you can prevent further problems with heavy cookie sites by going to **Settings|Advanced|Content Settings|Manage Exceptions**, and add the base site url (e.g. "msdn.microsoft.*" without the quotes) and select Behavior as "Clear on Exit".  You might have to login more often to these sites, but this should prevent the problem.

Comment: So why is this only on Chrome?

Comment: Good question @Wouter.  In my case I primarily use Chrome, so it could just be that I accumulate the most cookies there.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem when using ADB2C login from ASP.NET WebApp. In Firefox you can do similar use case to delete related coockies and problem is gone for a while. Click on HTTPS (i) lock icon with, select ">" button on the right, select More information, select Security tab, click on View Cookies and click on Remove All. Done 4 a while.

Answer (score 0):

If Above methods didn't work then enter

**chrome://settings/resetProfileSettings**

and Click on **Reset Settings**

This will reset your startup page, new tab page, search engine, and pinned tabs. It will also disable all extensions and clear temporary data like cookies. Your bookmarks, history and saved passwords will not be cleared.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me:
Run regedit to enter HKEY_ LOCAL_ MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP\Parameters

1. Add an item with type DWORD (32 bit), name MaxFieldLength, and value of decimal 32768;
2. Add an item with type DWORD (32 bit), name MaxRequestBytes, and value of decimal 32768.
3. Reboot takes effect: net stop http; net start http; iisreset